# Seaborn error: can't find 'height', where did it go?

Tags: python, seaborn, init

Just starting out with seaborn and ridgeline plotting. Still pretty new to Python and I'm working in Spyder 3. I wanted to first use the example shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})

# Create the data
rs = np.random.RandomState(1979)
x = rs.randn(500)
g = np.tile(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, g=g))
m = df.g.map(ord)
df["x"] += m

# Initialize the FacetGrid object
pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(10, rot=-.25, light=.7)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=15, height=.5, palette=pal)

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, shade=True, alpha=1, lw=1.5, bw=.2)
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2, bw=.2)
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=2, clip_on=False)

# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)

g.map(label, "x")

# Set the subplots to overlap
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)

# Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
```

This can also be found at https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html

I mainly wanted to see how everything functioned first before utilizing the package, but the 'height' parameter for FacetGrid isn't recognized through __ init __. Specifically the error reads:

"__ init __() got an unexpected keyword argument 'height'"

I've tried running it in both Python 2.7 and 3.5 with no luck. If this has been answered previously, please direct me to the right page as I've not been able to find the answer with my own searches.

Comment: Try size instead of height

Comment: code works fine on seaborn v.0.9.0, what version are you using?

Comment: [According to the docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#api-changes), the `height=` parameter was introduced in v.0.9.0, before, it was called `size=` as pointed out by @BossaNova

Comment: `pip install --upgrade seaborn` in case you were wondering how to get the latest version, since pip doesn't upgrade packages by default..

Comment: Thank you, the upgrade did the trick.